# Using htaccess to redirect subfolder and variable

Tags: .htaccess

I've written the following code so that `mysite.com/ticket/{n}` where `{n}` represents a number redirects to `othersite.com/ticket/{n}`.

So far not having much luck getting it working.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/ticket/(\d+)/?$ http://othersite.com/ticket/$1 [L]
```

Comment: For redirection use `[R]` flag.

Comment: Thanks but doesn't get it working.